# Forcing Laravel 4.2 to auto-download exported sheet using Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-excel

I am having a weird issue where I can't force Laravel to automatically download an exported sheet.

I know that the sheet is being generated because after I click on the link (at the bottom) I am taken to a blank page -- if I hit refresh on that page I automatically download the sheet I just exported and it looks fine. All I want to do is have the sheet automatically download but stay on the home page.

My Controller:

```
public function ListAll()
{
    Excel::create('Users', function($excel) {
      $excel->sheet('Users', function($sheet) {
        $users = User::orderBy('End_Enrollment','asc')->get();
        $sheet->fromArray($users);
      });
    })->export('xlsx');   // Have also tried ->download('xlsx') and have same issue.
    return View::make('/');
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/all', 'SearchController@ListAll');
```

The link on the website (html):

```
Click <a href="/all">here</a> to export the entire database.
```

I have read about a Response:: method, but I am unfamiliar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting target"_blank" in the link made this work.